# I am having trouble rendering the fields in in-built password reset confirm form

Tags: django, django-forms, python-3.7

When I use the in-built PasswordResetConfirmView the fields i.e. new password and password confirmation do not show up.  I get a blank form with only the submit button.

One of the previous posts mentioned that one could try removing crispy from the corresponding template, which I tried without success.

I also note that the password reset link thatI received in email looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset-confirm/MQ55a-1dead984b940e457bcad.  Note that it is not .../MQ/ as I see in the examples.  I tried inserting the / in the url but that did not load the template.

My url patterns...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'user/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name = 'user/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name = 'user/password_reset.html'),
                            name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset-done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name = 'user/password_reset_done.html'),
                            name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64><token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name = 'user/password_reset_confirm.html'),
                            name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

My password-reset-confirm.html is

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Enter New Password</legend>
                {{form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Change Password</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I expect to see the password and password confirm fields. Instead I get 
the screen which is at this link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E61fjoy5K26nA0Ooej56gRu0DPLFzfXo

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my url_patterns:

I had missed out the / between uidb64 and token parameters for the path password-reset-confirm